# The Lattice of all subvarieties of a variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, universal-algebra

Suppose that we have a variety $V$ and the corresponding lattice of all subvarieties. My question is: is that lattice an object of our ZFC theory?
Especially, is it small? If we take and element of it, say $V$ itself, then
$\bigcup V$is not a small set, hence the entire lattice is not small either.
I do not think that this question is particularly interesting, but I would like to see how it is formally treated that elements of supposedly small thing are not small themselves.

Comment: Unless $V$ itself is a set, no, formally these objects are not sets. Usually these are not real issues, though (either there is a natural way of coding the whole lattice as a proper class, or there is a set that in a natural way codes all the relevant lattice-theoretic structure).

Comment: BUT, the coding itself is not small either, right?It is a vicious circle.

Comment: What is a variety?

Comment: A class of algebras of the same type closed under the operators $H,S$ and $P$ in this order.Or a class of them definable by a small set of equalities.It is a Birkhoff's theorem that these definitions mean the same thing.

Comment: Do I get a choice in what are the meaning of the operators $H$, $S$ and $P$? And what does it mean for algebras to have the same type?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You with almost 300K Points are asking about this fundamental notions from universal algebra?$H,S$ and $P$ are operators standing for operators taking homomorphic image, subalgebras and products.The similarity type is some sequence of operations considered together with their arities. Say groups are 1 binary (*) 1 nullary (neutral element) and one unary (inverse). It is a good point to explain that without inverse the result will not be a variety.

Comment: "the coding itself is not small"  Obviously if dealing with proper classes, there will be proper classes involved; I am not sure I understand where you feel there is a problem. Do you understand how proper classes are treated in ZFC? I think you need to step back and ask another more basic question, or we won't get anywhere. Your most recent reply to Asaf is particularly troublesome.

Comment: The problem was how do I formalize the lattice of subvarieties of a variety $V$ in ZFC.I think that proper classes are those definable by a formula with parameters.I've tried to explain to Asaf the notion of a variety as best as possible and giving an example of my explanation at the same time.

Comment: What do my points have to do with my knowledge in algebra? I could equally say that with 1000+ points, you should be at the point where it's obvious to you what is a set and what isn't. So why are you even asking this question?

Comment: I feel sorry if you were offended by my comment. It was just a surprise for me that someone with such a score here could ask what is a variety. Nothing more and nothing less.It is obvious what is a class and what is a set, I was just curious how to **formalize** the notion of the lattice of all subvarieties when everything is imposed to be small.

Comment: @user122424 Unfortunately universal algebra is not a very widely-known area of mathematics. I estimate that if you polled all mathematicians, less than 10% would be able to tell you what a variety of algebras is. And it's possible that less than 10% would even be aware that such a concept exists.

Answer (score 4):

A variety as usually defined is of course a class, but you can encode the same information by identifying a variety with the set of identities that hold in it.  That is, you can instead define a variety over a signature to be a set of identities over that signature which is closed under deduction.  This makes the collection of all varieties over a given signature into a set.  (The "subvariety" order then corresponds to reverse inclusion on sets of identities: a set of identities $S$ corresponds to a subvariety of a set of identities $T$ if $S\supseteq T$.)

Comment: +1. Another approach: every variety is generated by a single algebra, so in some sense the variety itself represents the collection of all subvarieties - all that's missing is the relevant equivalence relation, which is clearly definable.